# java paho mqtt subscribe can't reconnect

Tags: java, mqtt, subscribe

I am using java paho mqtt.
I want to maintain subscribe connection always.
I think it will be auto connection..
but when server normalize finally after mqtt server shut down or restart,
client(subscribe) can't receive any message.
what's wrong?

```
public class MqttSubscribe {
MqttClient client;
MqttConnectOptions connOpt;


public MqttSubscribe() {

    mqtt_parse = new MqttParser();
    connOpt = new MqttConnectOptions();
    connOpt.setKeepAliveInterval(30);
    connOpt.setCleanSession(true);
    connOpt.setConnectionTimeout(2000);

    mqttSubConnect();

}

MqttCallback callback = new MqttCallback() {

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {

        System.out.println("connect loss");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mqttSubConnect();
    }


    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String arg0, MqttMessage msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(msg.toString());
    }

};

public void mqttSubConnect() {

    try {
        client = new MqttClient(
                SetDeviceSettingsValue.MQTT_BROKER_IP + ":" + SetDeviceSettingsValue.MQTT_BROKER_PORT,
                MqttClient.generateClientId(), new MemoryPersistence());
        client.setCallback(callback);
        client.connect(connOpt);
        client.subscribe(
        MqttTopic.MainTopic+"/"+ MqttJsonHeaderValue.DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS+"/"+MqttTopic.ControlTopic, 
          MqttQos.MQTT_QOS_2);

    } catch (MqttException e) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After the line `connOpt.setConnectionTimeout(2000);` try add this

```
connOpt.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
```

If set to true, in the event that the connection is lost, the client will attempt to reconnect to the server. It will initially wait 1 second before it attempts to reconnect, for every failed reconnect attempt, the delay will double until it is at 2 minutes at which point the delay will stay at 2 minutes.